# crystal report cross tab disappear when edit the procedure name

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have existing crystal report which is using stored procedure to bind the report field.

NOw, i need to change this procedure to another procedure version where some extra fields are existed.

So, i have change it from "Edit Command" by clicking at alias.

ProbleM: it does not show the "Cross tab" existed in report and all other things are fine.

Please share me what could be the cause.

Thanks

Comment: cross table means cross tab?

Comment: sorry, its cross tab !

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you make any changes to the `datasource` or update the `datasource`, Cross tab will be resetted and all its formatting will be lost and cross may also disappear.

Check whether the fields used in cross tab still exists after updation of the datasource. If those are missing then also there is possibility of losing the cross tab.

In this case you need to recreate the cross tab.

Comment: In newly added cross tab, it shows additional column for rows and additional row for header as - index number. How to remove that ?

Comment: Index like - sequence number, first column appear as index and same on oever header also.. how to remove this extra appearnace 1, 2, 3....

Comment: I guess since you have updated procedure there are new columns added in the cross tab... to get required columns you need to create a formula write `If` condition of required columns and use that formula in crosstab

Comment: No, there is same fields in both the procedure and no any new column in cross tab. But, it looks like some "order" kind of additional row/column apears..

Comment: In this case I guess those are `totals`.. go to cross tab expert and in that go to 3rd tab and supress the required totals